# New One or both of Username and Password are invalid. Error

Tags: docusignapi

We have been using the API for weeks with no issues, but suddenly we have one transaction that returns the error "New One or both of Username and Password are invalid".

I have tested with other transactions and they still work, all the transactions use the same PDF forms just the data is different (Credit applications).

Any ideas why just this one form would fail and the others still work perfectly?

Edit: Adding the example call here:

```
    <CreateAndSendEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
  <Envelope>
    <TransactionID>ACC-A06786408:28:47.7578750</TransactionID>
    <AccountId>[DSAccountID]</AccountId>
    <Documents>
      <Document>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>ACC-A067864_Combined_1015201582846.pdf</Name>
        <PDFBytes>[PDFBytes]</PDFBytes>
        <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
      </Document>
    </Documents>
    <Recipients>
      <Recipient>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <UserName>[DSUserName]</UserName>
        <SignerName>[SignerName]</SignerName>
        <Email>[DSUserEmail]</Email>
        <Type>InPersonSigner</Type>
        <AccessCode/>
        <CaptiveInfo>
          <ClientUserId>Signer1</ClientUserId>
        </CaptiveInfo>
        <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
      </Recipient>
      <Recipient>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <UserName>[DSUserName]</UserName>
        <SignerName>[SignerName2]</SignerName>
        <Email>[DSUserEmail]</Email>
        <Type>InPersonSigner</Type>
        <AccessCode/>
        <CaptiveInfo>
          <ClientUserId>Signer2</ClientUserId>
        </CaptiveInfo>
        <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
      </Recipient>
    </Recipients>
    <Tabs>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
        <AnchorTabItem>
          <AnchorTabString>PrimarySignature</AnchorTabString>
        </AnchorTabItem>
        <Type>SignHere</Type>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
        <AnchorTabItem>
          <AnchorTabString>PrimarySignature</AnchorTabString>
          <XOffset>200</XOffset>
        </AnchorTabItem>
        <Type>DateSigned</Type>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
        <AnchorTabItem>
          <AnchorTabString>PrimIn</AnchorTabString>
        </AnchorTabItem>
        <Type>InitialHere</Type>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
        <AnchorTabItem>
          <AnchorTabString>DealerSignature</AnchorTabString>
        </AnchorTabItem>
        <Type>SignHere</Type>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
        <AnchorTabItem>
          <AnchorTabString>DealerSignature</AnchorTabString>
          <XOffset>200</XOffset>
        </AnchorTabItem>
        <Type>DateSigned</Type>
      </Tab>
      <Tab>
        <DocumentID>2</DocumentID>
        <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
        <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
        <XPosition>100</XPosition>
        <YPosition>100</YPosition>
        <Type>SignerAttachment</Type>
      </Tab>
    </Tabs>
    <Subject>[EmailSubject]</Subject>
    <EmailBlurb/>
  </Envelope>
</CreateAndSendEnvelope>
```

Comment: Rest or soap? Which method / call fails? Did you look at the trace log?

Comment: Please post which exact API call you're making and what data you are sending (you can redact things that are private).  Otherwise this is nearly impossible to resolve based on the info you've provided...

Comment: Hi, we are using SOAP and the call fails on the CreateAndSendEnvelope call.  The API log gives the error: 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: It isn't letting my include the call, it's too long for a comment.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that they username and password you are passing are correct and valid in the environment? (I'm not sure if you're running against demo or production).  You can test by logging in to the console with those credentials.  If those are correct are you also positive that the Integrator Key you are testing with is valid and has not been disabled in your account preferences?

Comment: Yes I'm positive the username and password are correct, I can make the call with other applications and they work fine.  It seems to be isolated to this specific case that we get the error.

Comment: It's a little on the newer side of things so I haven't been able to test yet, but what exactly are you using the `transactionId` for?  I see through the SOAP API Guide that that's an optional element that is used to identify the envelope.  I'm not sure why that would be needed in addition to the unique `envelopeId` that is automatically generated for every envelope.  Are you sure that is not referencing another existing envelope in the system that you've created within the past 7 days?  Can you run a test without it in there to make sure that's not the issue?

Comment: I'm using the transactionid as our internal tracking, I just tried without passing a transactionid and I received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the help of support.  There was an error with the initial tab on page 5 of this certain set of documents.  They were able to help me track down the actual error instead of the generic username/password error.